# Date conversion Simple Date format

Tags: java, jsp, date

I need to convert the date to this format yyyy.mm.dd and i am using the below formula -

```
Date curDate = new Date();
out.println(curDate);
String pattern = "yyyy.mm.dd";

DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
String DateToStr = format1.format(curDate);
out.println(DateToStr);
```

The output i am getting is

```
curDate - Fri Feb 05 15:21:28 CST 2016
DateToStr - 2016.21.05
```

I need instead of 2016.21.05, it should be DateToStr - 2016.02.05.

Any help what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: mm is for minutes, MM is for months

Comment: @ArunK Please search StackOverflow before posting. This issue has been covered many many times already. You would have found hundreds of working code examples against which you could compare your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `yyyy.MM.dd` = year.month.day, while `yyyy.mm.dd` = year.minute.day.

See this [cheat sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/23/date-formatting-in-c) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I was struggling for some time should have checked earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
String pattern = "yyyy.MM.dd";
```

and read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)